# Is my 75” TV Mount Falling Off?

Tags: mounting, television, mount

I recently mounted a 75” TV into timber studs through plasterboard.

The Mount feels very solid, but I can now see a little bulge and cracks in the plasterboard under the bottom mounting bolts. The whole house is shaking from
Wind today and the TV keeps creaking, unsure if it’s the Mount coming off.

The vertical line under the mount is pencil, the horizontal/diagonal line is a small crack in the plasterboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if it was pulling out, then the bulge would be above the mount

Comment: If those lag screws were placed into studs, then that mount will not come down without taking the house with it.  Plasterboard is quite weak and if wind is shaking the house, might find other small cracks here and there if you look.  The mount probably placed extra stress on that section of plasterboard.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from the picture, but it looks like a nail/screw pop because you've pulled the plasterboard closer to the stud. Wave a strong magnet near the spot and see if you find metal. Or excavate with a knife. Or ignore it until something changes dramatically.

Comment: If your house is shaking in a little wind I'm not sure you can expect _anything_ to remain secure. :O

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal crack in the bottom left looks painted over. Perhaps it’s been there? As for the other small vertical crack, I tend to agree with Aloysius, might be a screw pop of sorts.

How old is the house?